# Create new stub method that checks if the method exists in Rspec

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, stub, stubbing

I would like to create some especial stub methods `stub_check` and `stub_chain_check` that ensure the method exists.

For example:

```
#spec/controllers/payments_controller_spec.rb`

describe PaymentsController do
  it "makes a payment" do
    # Ensure method exists, Payment.new.respond_to?(:pay)
    # the API of Payment can change and tests will pass
    raise "Stubbing wrong method Payment#pay method doesn't exists" unless Payment.new.respond_to?(:pay)
    Payment.any_instance.stub(pay: true) # We can stub method now
    # Code...
  end
end
```

But I would like to to somwthing like `Payment.stub_check(pay: true)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper on your spec_helper.rb file:

```
def stub_check(resource, method, value, message)
  raise message unless resource.new.respond_to?(method)
  resource.any_instance.stub(method => value)
end
```

and you call it with

```
stub_check(Payment, :pay, true, 'Stubbing wrong method Payment#pay method doesn't exists')
```

EDIT: if you want this to work like stub, you may need to modify mocka or the matchers your are using (I guess it's mocka because of the "any_instance" method)

Comment: I have  thought about that one, and it's not a good Idea to use resourse.new.respond_to? method, it's better resource.method_defined? method, but I would like to do Payment.stub_check